# social share button in angular 10 ngx-sharebuttons

Tags: facebook, icons, whatsapp, angular10, share-button

I am implementing the ngx-sharebuttons for social share button like facebook, whatsapp.

this is what I tried

installed package

1. npm i cdk
2. npm i ngx-sharebuttons
3. npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons

```
import { ShareButtonsModule } from 'ngx-sharebuttons/buttons';
import { ShareIconsModule } from 'ngx-sharebuttons/icons';
```

```
 ShareButtonsModule.withConfig({
      debug: true
    }),
    ShareIconsModule
```

```
<share-buttons [theme]="'material-dark'"
[include]="['facebook','twitter','linkedin','pinterest','reddit','mix','vk','telegram','messenger','whatsapp','xing','line','sms','email','copy']"
[show]="9"
[size]="1"
[url]="'https://www.eduforbetterment.com/generate-qr-code-in-angular/'"
[image] ="'https://www.eduforbetterment.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/qrcode.jpg'"
[autoSetMeta]="false"
></share-buttons>
```

everything is working but I am not able to see the social icons for share like facebook, twitter, whatsapp and so on.

I followed this [link](https://www.eduforbetterment.com/angular-10-social-sharing-button/)

[image: share button is creating but not icons are not creating]

As you can see in the image share button is creating but icons are not creating.

below is my package.json file

```
"@angular-devkit/core": "10.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "10.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng-chartist": "4.1.0",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.4",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I used fontawesome icons instead (you import what you need)

```
import { faFacebookF, faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
constructor(
    iconLibrary: FaIconLibrary,
  ) {
    iconLibrary.addIcons(faTwitter, faFacebookF);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

[shareButton] is a directive that converts its host element to a share button.

https://ngx-sharebuttons.netlify.app/#/share-button-directive